# Multimeter capacitance value - ADC readings

Tags: voltage, adc, multimeter

I have set up my raspberry pi to read from the MAX1204. To know if I'm reading the proper value, I use a multimeter at the input channel of the ADC, and compare it to what I read through my program. This works great. However, when I disconnect my multimeter, I don't read the same value. If I was reading 1.264 - 1.268 (correct measurement), I now read 1.248- 1.252.

I assume it's due to the internal capacitance of the multimeter, or some other reason. How can I set up a capactiance or a way to read the correct readings without constantly needing to have the multimeter plugged in? I tried using a 0.01uF, 0.1uF and no luck.

Block Diagram (to try and replicate schematic):

[image]

Edit: it would seem that when changing my multimeter to the 2V option va the 20V, thé close it 1.276 but the ADC is still reading 1.25. Which means I have a 25 mV difference between voltage and readings.

Comment: What is the source of the voltage you are measuring and its source impedance? What is the internal impedance of your multimeter? (usually 10M\$\Omega\$ or 1M\$\Omega\$).

Comment: The voltage is measured after several buffers. My multimeters is this one:  http://rcce.com/rcc507-digital-multimeter , not exactly sure how to find the impendence

Comment: Have you looked at the signal with an oscilloscope?

Comment: No I haven’t. It’s a DC voltage btw. I don’t believe I mentioned that.

Comment: I understand you believe it to be a DC voltage, but it would be nice to confirm it.

Comment: The source comes from the output of a 12 to 5 V LDO that passes through a first buffer, gets divided with a voltage divider by a factor of 4, and enters another buffer which then enters the ADC. I won’t be able to get the measurements on the oscilloscope before Thursday afternoon unfortunately ( won’t have access to the school lab till then ).

Comment: The only thing I can suggest at this point is that you edit your question to include your full schematic, including all parts that are actually assembled. Maybe we can see something.

Comment: I’ll draw a block diagram soon and upload it. Thank you

Comment: Schematic != block diagram

Comment: I added a block diagram with IC's and voltage references

Comment: What voltages do you get with the multimeter at OP1 in and out, and OP2 in? The op amp may be sensitive to the varying capacitive load of the ADC (refer to datasheet section 7.3.6 "Capacitive Load and Stability"). What happens if you insert a 100 ohm resistor between the op amp and ADC?

Comment: I can and will redo the measurements, but I'll have to get back to you on Thursday with the numbers. If I remember correctly they were very close if not exact to the the 5.06 in and out for OP1, and 1.26 in+ and OUT for the OP2. I'll try adding a resistor between the op amp and ADC to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It sounds like the (usually very long) leads to the multimeter and then to ground may be picking up some interfering signal (possibly from AC mains).

Comment: So you believe the multimeter connection is adding noise to my circuit?